# Google Sheet Named Range Multiple Columns

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, named-ranges, importrange

In Column B I have drinks listed from B2:B100, In Column D I have food items listed from D2:D100. In another google sheet I need to have a single dropdown that needs to pull all the drinks and food items. I created a named range from B2:B100 and called it drinks. I have the importrange working to pull the drinks named range.

How can I get a named range of "drinks and food" with the value of B2:100 & D2:D100.
Then I will update my name range parameter in the importrange with the "drinks and food"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put them in array:

```
={B2:100; D2:D100}
```

or:

```
={drinks; food}
```

or:

```
={IMPORTRANGE("ID", "B2:B100"); IMPORTRANGE("ID", "D2:D100")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title of this question someone might find it useful to know that you can create a named range with multiple columns and all rows by omitting the row numbers.

For instance, a named range on a tab called 'tab_1' that includes columns A to C, and all rows, including those added to the sheet after the creation of the named range is created using this formula

```
'tab_1'!A:C
```

Comment: please explain how your solution suits the content of the entire enquiry.

Comment: It doesn't, it just matches the title and I kept finding myself here with the same question. I thought I'd try and help people out but if that's not how it's done I'm happy for my answer to be deleted.